# LLVM IR and floating point numbers

Tags: assembly, floating-point, hex, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm trying to figure out how to write out non-exact floating point numbers in LLVM (such as 1.3). This is what the [documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#simple-constants) has to say about them:

> The assembler requires the exact decimal value of a floating-point constant. For example, the assembler accepts 1.25 but rejects 1.3 because 1.3 is a repeating decimal in binary.

To try this out, I wrote the following code in C and made Clang output the IR.

```
int main() {
  float t = 0x3fa66666;
  printf("%f\n", t);
}


// LLVM IR:
define i32 @main() #0 {
  %t = alloca float, align 4
  store float 0x41CFD33340000000, float* %t, align 4
  %1 = load float* %t, align 4
  %2 = fpext float %1 to double
  %3 = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0), double %2)
  ret i32 0
}
```

What I don't understand here is where does 0x41CFD33340000000 come from and how is it calculated? At first I just figured that it was a double precision number, but when I converted it to 32-bit IEEE-754 floating point number I got 0x4E7E999A.

Comment: What do you expect that the line `float t = 0x3fa66666;` does in C?

Comment: @PascalCuoq I was expecting it to set t to 1.3, but I see now that it does not.

Comment: In C, the line `float t = 0x3fa66666;` is equivalent to `float t = (float) 0x3fa66666;` and sets `t` to the `float` nearest to the integer `0x3fa66666`. You could write `float t = 1.3f;`, that seems to be what you are looking for (in contrast `float t = 1.3;` technically contains a conversion from `double` to `float`, but this conversion applied to a constant may well already be simplified in the IR you get to observe).

Comment: 0x3fa66666 = 1067869798 and is represented as [0x41CFD33333000000 in double precision](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=049048054055056054057055057056). The difference is because 0x3fa66666 is stored in float precision first then promoting to double in printf